# Is it possible to use a brace-enclosed initializer list for a container of a container?

Tags: c++, initializer-list

I understand that from C++11 I can initialise a container using a brace-enclosed initializer list:

```
std::map<int, char> m = {{1, 'a'}, {3, 'b'}, {5, 'c'}, {7, 'd'}};
```

Is this also possible for containers of containers?

For example, I have tried the following without success:

```
std::pair<std::map<int, char>, int> a = {{1, 'c'}, 2};
```

In Visual Studio 2015 I receive the following compile error:

> no instance of constructor "std::map<_Kty, _Ty, _Pr, _Alloc>::map [with _Kty=std::map, std::allocator>>, _Ty=int, _Pr=std::less, std::allocator>>>, _Alloc=std::allocator, std::allocator>>, int>>]" matches the argument list
>               argument types are: ({...}, int)

With MinGW32 the compile error was along the lines of

> Could not convert {...} from brace-enclosed initializer list to std::pair...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are missing brackets for your map (and `"c"` should be `'c'` because `"c"` is a `const char *` not a `char`, thanks to Bastien Durel):

```
std::pair<std::map<int, char>, int> a = {{{1, 'c'}}, 2};
```

To use initializer list to initialize a map, you need a "list of pairs", something like `{{key1, value1}, {key2, value2}, ...}`. If you want to put this in a pair, you need to add another level of brackets, which yield `{{{key1, value1}, {key2, value2}, ...}, second}`.

Comment: and `"c"` is not a char but a const char[]

Comment: @BastienDurel You're right, I did not notice it, answer updated!

Comment: Yes, I seem to have made some fundamental errors in my testing.  Strange that `std::pair<std::map<int, int>, int> a5 = { {1, 1}, 1 };` is fine but `std::pair<std::map<int, char>, int> a6 = { {1, 'c'}, 2 };` is not.  In Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: @rasteve Intelissence doesn't seem to detect the error when you write `{{1, 1}, 1}` but the code doesn't compile (at least on my computer with VS2015), I got a "illegal indirection" error pointing to the `xtree` file.